# Should [star-trek-emh] be renamed [emergency-medical-hologram]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag for The Doctor from *Star Trek: Voyager*, officially the [Emergency Medical Hologram Mark I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)), is currently [star-trek-emh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-emh). Since we can use longer tag names for quite a while now, should we rename that to [emergency-medical-hologram](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-medical-hologram) and use the old tag as a synonym?

If so, would a mod please be so kind?

Comment: Already discussed here: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/tag-the-doctor-doctor-who-or-voyager. I thoroughly enjoy the current `star-trek` tagging system, it makes tags very easy to find and logical to fix. Probably one of the best tagging systems we have on site.

Answer (score -1):

#### Make it so.

Rename the current tag to [emergency-medical-hologram](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency-medical-hologram) and make [star-trek-emh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-emh) a synonym.

Using [the-doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-doctor) as a synonym is not a good idea, since that's a common name for Dr. Who.
We *could* add [star-trek-doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-doctor), but that might cause confusion with dr. Leonard "Bones" McCoy from the Original Series of *Star Trek*.